# ES6 destructuring with expression

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have the following code

```
let { searchTerm: searchTerm = '' } = this.state;

searchTerm = decodeURIComponent(searchTerm)
```

Which works, but I was wondering if it was possible to embed the expression (decodeURIComponent call) inside the destructuring like

```
const { decodeURIComponent(searchTerm) : searchTerm = '' } = this.state;
//or
const { searchTerm = searchTerm ? decodeURIComponent(searchTerm) : '' } = this.state;
```

But those syntaxes are illegal or plain don't work.
Haven't found documentation that shows how to, yet, looking at the grammar, it seems it somehow should work, ie it uses the same "initializer" rule

From this grammar rule
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment

look at AssignmentElement definition

Then go to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer

then look at Initializer definition

Then look at
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators

Comment: At some point, it probably just makes sense to skip the destructuring:  `let searchTerm = decodeURIComponent(this.state.searchTerm || "");`.

Comment: The *Initialiser* is the `''` expression after the `=`. The `decodeURIComponent(searchTerm)` in your code clearly is no *IdentifierReference*

Comment: Also see [early errors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment-static-semantics-early-errors) of the assignment expression. And when you're using `const`, it's actually a [*BindingPattern*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-binding-patterns) not an assignment.